# can the spring mechanism in a mepla match cabinet hinge be replaced?

Tags: cabinets, hinges

The "spring" for this mepla hinge has broken.  It's shown left of the hinge in this photo, "appearing" to be unbroken.  Is there anyplace i can get new spring?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that you can get a new spring, but the good news is that you'll be able to find a new euro cup hinge. Take the entire unit (including the base plate that's still attached to the cabinet) to a cabinetry supplier. If you don't have one, refer to the Blum catalog and try to match the relevant offsets. (Hint: this is hard, as there are a zillion different combinations available.) Replace all the hinges on the door -- don't mix and match.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the hinge to a home store like Home Depot or Lowe's.  I just replaced  a number of similar hinges and they have a huge selection. You'll need to buy the entire hinge but they are not expensive.

Comment: FWIW, my home derpo/lowes have terrible selections of hinges. The OP might get lucky, but I wouldn't bet on it. My cabinet/door place has an entire aisle devoted to euro hinges.

Comment: I second @AloysiusDefenestrate. Home Depot only has 1 Everbilt hinge for each broad category (35mm, soft/normal closing, overlay type). I bought one of these and the mounting holes are several mm offset from the old Mepla hinge. So if there are plastic dowels inset in the door or cabinet frame, you will need to remove these or drill through them, before Everbilt will work. This might be true for other brands as well, so check the schematics of the distances between the mounting holes.

Answer (score 1):

The Mepla hinges are no longer made, nor available except (sometimes) on eBay. As one hardware store [puts it](https://buildershardwaremi.com/infamous-mepla-hinge-replacing-pie-cut-corner-hinges/): "*Fortunately, the **Mepla hinge isn’t in production anymore due to its design flaws**. Unfortunately, that means it is hard to find a replacement*."

I just needed to replace 30-year-old Mepla cabinet hinges as well, and one had a broken spring part like yours. Ideally, I agree it would be elegant and frugal to buy replacement (sub)components for devices which are "mostly" still in good condition. However, it's really not economical for items this cheap (for the manufacturer, and probably not for consumers). Hinges like this can be bought at box stores like HD for about $12/pair; and I've seen (probably better) products at online cabinet/hardware suppliers for as low as $3.50 each.

Stock availability aside, my 35mm full overlay hinge does not seem to be serviceable. The "spring leaf" part is anchored on four (or more) tiny pins that function like axels, but seem to be capped or rivited at the ends so they can't be removed. In fact, I'm not sure if I can dismantle any more parts to this, additional to the primary parts for adjustment and attachment to the cabinets.